# Flask 'loses' the static folder when I add a url subpath level i.e. shop/cart. It routes to the cart page but can't find my CSS, JS, etc

Tags: python-3.x, flask, url-routing, templating

My Flask has no problems with the static folder (applications/static) when the URL route for the page it's calling is singular (i.e. `@app.route("/shop/")`).

terminal output:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Jul/2020 17:56:11] "GET /shop/ HTTP/1.1" 200
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Jul/2020 17:56:11] "GET /static/img/shop/products/5.j
pg HTTP/1.1" 200
...
```

Here's the problem:

But, as soon as I add a level for the cart.html, using `@app.route("/shop/cart/")`, Flask 'loses' its mind and begins looking for the static folder here:

terminal output:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Jul/2020 17:56:20] "GET /shop/cart/ HTTP/1.1" 200
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Jul/2020 17:56:20] "GET /shop/static/css/plugins.min.
css HTTP/1.1" 404
```

Now, it routs to the /shop/cart/ page, but with no static resources, just HTML.

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to generat those static URLs?

Comment: Sure, `@app.route("/shop/")
def shop():
    return render_template('shop.html')`

Comment: `@app.route("/shop/cart/")
def cart():
    return render_template('cart.html')`

Comment: `from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static')`

Comment: Sorry that code is not generating the urls.  I mean like the `{{ url_for() }}` functions from the template.  Also you may wish to remove the trailing slashes on each of the URLs you posted above.  `@app.route("/shop")` etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Your question about route made me question the resource routes from the .HTML files. I think that's what you were asking, instead of from the app.py.  I'm posting the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I was using `href` or `src="../static/resource"` from my HTML files to map resources. This is proper resource routing relative to the template files. However, with some research, I realized that Flask looks for resources based on the location of the applications folder when matching resources to HTML documents.

Coming from a non-templating background and WordPress, I'm used to routing relative to the document I'm working in or not having to worry about the logic at all. So, the solution was to go through my HTML documents and find all "`..`" and replace them with nothing, effectively deleting them and leaving my routes as `href` or `src="/static/resource"` and not `href` or `src="../static/resource"`